# RegEx: Best way to search and replace $!esc.html($!{XYZ})

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext, regex-group

I have inherited a project that includes html email templates and the text files that get sent along with it.

The back-end puts it all together, so that it's a multipart email message in the end. In other words, if someone has HTML turned off, they can read the text version. TMI.

**Problem:**

The guy before me left all kinds of `$!esc.html($!{XYZ})` in the text files. Where `XYZ` stands for various different strings in the code.

I haven't touched RegEx in years and am at a loss.

**Question**

Is it possible to look for every occurrence of such variables in the text files and replace it with: `$!{LAST_NAME}`?

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have tried one of those RegEx recipe sites, but I got stuck. Any suggestions and/or help with this would be tremendously appreciated.

I am using SublimeText3, and I know how to find & replace in `.txt` files only.

Peace. Calm. Light.

Comment: `\$!esc\.html\(\$!{XYZ}\)` replace with `$!{LAST_NAME}`? You just need to escape regex special chars (i.e. `$().`). Is `XYZ` a placeholder for your actual values by any chance? If that's the case, what's the format? If it's always uppercase letters you can use `[A-Z]+`.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more accurate: XYZ typically stands for `register_now` or `download_free_trial`. I appreciate your swift response.

Comment: In that case replace `XYZ` in my original comment with `\w+`, thus `\$!esc\.html\(\$!{\w+}\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what 'flavor' of regex sublime uses, but this should work. I'm assuming the `XYZ` means it will only be letters in there?

`\$!esc\.html\(\$!\{\w*\}\)`

The following version accounts for any `_`'s

`\$!esc\.html\(\$!\{(\w|_)*\}\)`

Comment: Yes, I should have been more accurate: XYZ typically stands for `register_now` or `download_free_trial`. I appreciate your swift response.

Comment: @ShawnSpencer updated post with a 2nd version, which sounds like the one you will want to use